# Unable to Install Any App On Mac M1 Running With Monterey 12.5 version. Even though I have done CHMODE permission settings but still no success

Tags: macos

I am trying to install an application but whenever I try to open the app (after mounting the dmg file), it gives me the following error (screenshot attached):

[image: error screenshot]

Even though I have done CHMODE permission settings but still no success. Example: chmod +x .app/Contents/MacOS/

I have enabled the Allow Apps from Anywhere on Mac M1 as well via terminal. Now "anywhere" option is visible in System Preferences >> Security & Privacy >> General Tab.

But still I am unable to Install Any App On Mac M1 Running With Monterey 12.5 version.

Please advice what could be the reason for the same.

Comment: It might help to know what the app is. Is it designed to be run initially from the dmg, as an installer, rather than being dragged to ~/Applications? Have you tried Right click/Open, rather than double-click?

Comment: sorry for late answer. I am trying to install Parallels software on Mac. But its not allowing me to install.

Comment: You're probably better off asking Parallels.